# template class memory cleanup issue

Tags: c++

I have a problem that I can't seem to think on good solution besides trying to go to assembly to do the memory cleanup or subclassing by template argument pointers and values.
I wanted to use my class like this where the memory is cleaned up on desctructor if needed:

```
CDummyObject<int> obj1(123, CDummyObject<int>::eValue); //No cleanup needed
CDummyObject<int*> obj2(new int, CDummyObject<int*>::eNewPtr); //Need to call delete
```

But got errors on destructor because when the typename used is a value it cannot have code like delete or free using the template. Any tips on how to trick the compiler to ignore the errors and just compile since I have got them properly protected?

The class definition is something like:

```
template<typename Type>
class CDummyObject
{
public:
    typedef enum
    {
        eInvalid,
        eValue,
        eNewPtr,
        eNewPtrArray,
        eMallocPtr
    } EParameterType;
private:
    Type _DummyVar;
    EParameterType _VarType;
public:
    CDummyObject(Type var, EParameterType type)
    {
        _DummyVar = var;
        _VarType = type;
    }

    ~CDummyObject()
    {
        switch (_VarType) //Free the memory if needed
        {
        case eNewPtr:
            if (_DummyVar) delete _DummyVar;
            break;
        case eNewPtrArray:
            if (_DummyVar) delete[] _DummyVar;
            break;
        case eMallocPtr:
            if (_DummyVar) free(_DummyVar);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define helper functions as function templates. The overload which takes pointer releases memory, the overload for non-pointer types does nothing:

```
private:
    Type _DummyVar;
    EParameterType _VarType;

    template<class T> void deleter(T) {  /* nothing to do for non-pointer types*/ }

    template<class T> void deleter(T*) { // this overload is called for pointer types
        switch (_VarType) //Free the memory if needed
        {
        case eNewPtr:
            if (_DummyVar) delete _DummyVar;
            break;
        case eNewPtrArray:
            if (_DummyVar) delete[] _DummyVar;
            break;
        case eMallocPtr:
            if (_DummyVar) free(_DummyVar);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }        
    }

public:
    // dtor
    ~CDummyObject() {
        deleter(_DummyVar); // while instatiating the right deleter method is selected
    }
```

Comment: After a good night of sleep, I had something like this in mind, instead of going to assembly, subclassing or template specialization, but your suggestion is even cleaner/simpler than what I had thought. Thank you for this elegant way of doing the cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix compile-time template types with runtime if's. If you provide `int` to your class as a template type then the compiler still has to be able to compile all of:

```
case eNewPtr:
    if (_DummyVar) delete _DummyVar;
    break;
case eNewPtrArray:
    if (_DummyVar) delete[] _DummyVar;
    break;
case eMallocPtr:
    if (_DummyVar) free(_DummyVar);
    break;
```

And it will complain since it can't call `delete`/`free` on a non-pointer.

Consider using `if constexpr` instead if your C++ version allows it along with type traits to determine if `Type` is a pointer or not.

Comment: I know the reason, but everything will be just a register value on the processor that doesn't care about types, it's just a compiler protection. Nevertheless, I think that your suggestion would solve my problem without major changes but unfortunately, it is not available to me C++17.

Comment: Pre-C++17 you can use things like SFINAE and [enable_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).  `_VarType` will probably need to become part of a traits class so you can use it in compile-time conditionals.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about SFINAE. That would have worked also, but I went with another answer, for what I need to do it suffices and is simpler. I will keep this in mind for more complex class templates behavior. Thank you.